Difference between 'had something done' and 'got something done' as causative verb

He had got a letter of recommendation written.


He had had a letter of recommendation written.

When we use 'get' as a causative verb followed by the object, we generally take past participle with it. Can we also do the same practice with 'have' as causative verb? What is the difference between these two sentences? Are both of them correct?

This question is similar to: "Using Causative Verbs". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Edit
The use of the past participle after the object of the causative verb HAVE in your example is fine, and both examples are correct.
The causative verbs got and had here have similar meanings, but the latter is slightly more formal.
Outside of this question, in the following sentences,
He got her to write a letter.
He had her write a letter.
the first one has a hint of effort and convincing from him.
Edit
We look at another pair of examples:

I got SOMETHING DONE.


I had SOMETHING DONE.

The first one can occasionally mean I did it myself, usually with some difficulties or delays, but the second one can never have this additional meaning.

I agree - not that 'get something done' implies force, but that there's a hint of difficulty.

Ignoring the (irrelevant, imho) casting of OP's examples in Past Perfect, another difference is that 1) I got the wall replastered could sometimes mean I personally replastered it (often by implication, ...with some difficulty / after some delay), whereas 2) I had the wall replastered can only ever mean ...by someone else.

In AmE, not necessarily force, and not necessarily difficulty. Perhaps just a request to write on his behalf.  She did  not come to him and volunteer to write the letter.  I thought to myself, you should get your tutor to write a letter of recommendation. She is still junior faculty but she knows your work best. So I got her to write the letter, and the rest is history.

Thanks, @FumbleFingers. I've added your input to my answer.

You've already got this. 'Had it done' is more genteel, 'got' is OK in the trailer park but if you think there's any nuance such as in hindi (compound verbs can show benefit flow towards the subject), sadly, no.

The trailer park comment is misleading. People in all walks of life use "get" in this manner. The comment is also needlessly offensive. The downvote is not mine, BTW.

Irony is an extension of humour. You didn't note that I opened with 'got'
